# How to efficiently calculate binomial probability with list of probabilities? in R

Tags: r

I have a list of probabilities of success for independent events:

```
probs <- c(.2,.3,.4)
```

I want to write a function that answers the question: what is probability of getting at least X successes from these independent events?

My current approach is to run the following code thousands of times using a for loop. Is there a more efficient way?

```
sim_results <- probs - runif(length(probs), 0, 1)
length(sim_results[sim_results > 0])
```

Comment: Are you doing this for pedagogical reasons or because you want to know the result?  Because it's really trivial if you just want the probability ...

Comment: If you're just looking for the expected value of three independent Bernoulli random variables, that's not a programming question. Sounds like you need a stats tutor rather than a programmer. Do you have a programming question that i'm missing here?

Comment: I'm asking how to write code in R that answers this question. It is probably very easy, but the code I wrote is very slow with a large size of "probs".

Comment: it should be sufficient just to compute `sum(probs > runif(length(probs)))`.

Comment: I think that just tells you how many trials were successful. I'm interested in the probability of getting X or more success in Y trials given a list of probabilities of independent events

Comment: The probability will be given by the histogram of the simulated outcomes. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to generate all random numbers in one shot and avoid for loops.

```
# number of random probabilities
p = 100
# number of simulations
N = 1000
# random probabilities
probs = runif(p)
M = matrix(runif(p*N), N, p)
# outcome
y = apply(M,1,function(x) sum(probs>x))
hist(y)
```